# How do i get this If/else statement to work correctly?

Tags: javascript

I'm practicing functions and stumped. The code only produces the if block regardless of prompt. Is this a type conversion thing. What am I missing?

```
function init() {
  function dogAllowed(breed) {
    var breed = prompt("what type of dog");
    if (breed = "pitbull") {
      console.log("dogNotAllowed");
    } else {
      console.log("dog Allowed");
    }
  }
  dogAllowed();
}
window.onload = init();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `if` statement, you need comparison equals (`==`) not assignment equals (`=`). So: `if (breed == "pitbull")` should work.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison operator in JavaScript is `==`, or `===` for strict equality. `=` is an assignment operator ("put the value on the right inside the variable on the left), and it happens returns the value that was assigned. Here, that value is `"pitbull"`, so your `if (breed = "pitbull")` is equivalent to `breed = "pitbull"` followed by `if ("pitbull")`. JavaScript evaluates non-empty string as true, so you always enter the first branch of that `if`.

`if (breed === "pitbull")` should work, and so should `if (breed == "pitbull")`. Read more about the difference between the two at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not doing a closure, I would recommend separating the functions and also using a ternary operator. I also think you should properly indent your code because it well help people understand it better.

As the other answers mentioned you are using an assignment operator `=` when you should be using an equality operator. I recommend to never use `==` because it does type conversion which can lead to more problems later on. Personally I always use `===` and do the data type conversion myself rather than leaving it up to javascript because its much less prone to bugs.

You can separate your functions like this:

```
function init() {
  dogAllowed();
}

function dogAllowed (breed) {
  var breed = prompt("What breed of dog?");
  console.log(breed === "pitbull" ? "Dog not allowed" : "Dog allowed" )
}

window.onload = init();
```